# How to check inside where in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have these tables:

```
merchants:  id - name - set_local - city_id
products:   name - price - merchant_id (relation with merchants)
users:      name - email - city_id - etc ..
```

`set_local`  means if the merchant make it `true` the products just show up to users that's belongs to the same city  that merchant belongs

my wrong try:

```
$products = Product::whereHas('merchant',function($query){

            $query->where('set_local',true,function($query){
                $query->where('city_id',user()->city_id);
            });

        })
       ->take(16)
       ->get();
```

How can I check if it's true show the product to just users that the same of city of  merchant ?

Answer (score 1):

#### based on you

```
merchants:  id - name - set_local - city_id
products:   name - price - merchant_id (relation with merchants)
users:      name - email - city_id - etc ..
```

try `where([])`

```php
$products = Product::whereHas('merchant', function ($query) {
            $query->where([
                'set_local' => true,
                'city_id' => auth()->user()->city_id
            ]);
        })->take(16);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221914/discussion-on-answer-by-kamlesh-paul-how-to-check-inside-where-in-laravel).